# how to make RichTextBox print text without deleting previous line

Tags: visual-studio-2008

```
        Do

        RichTextBox1.Text = n

        n = n * 2

    Loop Until n = 1024
```

The problem is every time RichTextBox print text, it deletes the previously written text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are telling it to. You need to append not replace. Try this.

```
RichTextBox1.Text &= n.ToString & vbCrLf
```